# Chromedriver does not start when not SSH into the machine using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ssh, selenium-chromedriver

I am having troubles running a python bot with selenium on my server. The script works whenever I run it during an SSH session. I put up a Cronjob because I want the script to run at different times of the day. As soon as I log out of the SSH session the chromedriver does not start anymore. I get following error message in my syslog (I am not sure if this is the cause of the problem):
`kernel: [80703.867996] audit: type=1400 audit(1686739382.090:29475): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromedriver" name="/proc/31017/mem" pid=31017 comm="a3c817e265ab684" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000`

From Python I get the stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/../main.py", line 16, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 49, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 51, in **init**
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 97, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

I came across the `nohup` command but that does not seem so solve the problem.

Any Ideas what might cause the issue?

Comment: I solved the Problem: I did the python3 command from the crontab file. But that is not the way to do it. I put only the command to run a shell script into the crontab file. In the shell script I defined the Python3 command. Now it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:
When Ubuntu users log out of a machine their home directory is beeing encrypted. I moved the project files to /bin/ directory.
Another problem was with the installer (not apt-get, I forgot the name). It installed chromedriver automatically to the home directory. I manually installed it to the /usr/bin folder. After these changes it worked fine.
Anther important note: Always run Shell scripts with a Cronjob, never run the Python script directly.